# Change color tr onclick

Tags: html, css, row, html-table

I have this code, when the row is clicked the row is changed to 'selected_row'. When clicked again it´s supposed to change back to '$class', but it doesn't. What is causing the trouble and how can I solve this?

```
$class = ($class == 'even') ? 'odd' : 'even';

echo '<tr class="'.$class.'" onclick="this.className=this.className==\'selected_row\'? '.$class.' :\'selected_row\';">
```

Comment: Incidentally, JavaScript works on the html as seen by the browser; for JS questions it's better to show the rendered html (view source) than the server-side script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could try this, simply place the function below within the  section of your html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleClass(ele,customClass)
{
    ele.className=ele.className=='selected_row' ? customClass:'selected_row';
}
</script>
```

Then change your existing syntax from:

```
echo '<tr class="'.$class.'" onclick="this.className=this.className==\'selected_row\'? '.$class.' :\'selected_row\';">
```

To:

```
echo '<tr class="'.$class.'" onclick="toggleClass(this,\''.$class.'\');"><td>apple</td></tr>';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing quote behind the last `$class`.

I think these kind of syntax errors should show up when you use FireBug or similar debugging tools.

Comment: Not sure about that. When I use onclick="this.className=this.className==\'selected_row\'? \'odd\' :\'selected_row\';" it works fine. For some reason $class won't work.

Comment: Yes, as Golez said, you're missing `\'` quotes around that `$class`. Having quotes-inside-quotes is very confusing, which is why you should be breaking this out into Unobtrusive JavaScript instead of putting code in inline event handlers.